# Ruby on Rails - issues with sqlite3 gem install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I am learning from the rails tutorial at [Rails Tutorial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html)

using Mac OS

When i try the `bin/rails server` command i get the below errors.

```
bin/rails server
Could not find gem 'uglifier (>= 1.3.0) ruby' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile or installed on this machine.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

Successively when i try the `bundle install` command i get the bellow issues.

```
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for sqlite3.h... yes
checking for sqlite3_libversion_number() in -lsqlite3... no
sqlite3 is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal',
'yum install sqlite-devel' or 'apt-get install libsqlite3-dev'
and check your shared library search path (the
location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
    --with-sqlite3-dir
    --without-sqlite3-dir
    --with-sqlite3-include
    --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
    --with-sqlite3-lib
    --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/
    --with-sqlite3lib
    --without-sqlite3lib


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/lloyd/dev/projects/blog/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/lloyd/dev/projects/blog/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.10), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.10'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I have tried system install, vendor install. Even tried installing sqlite3 using homebrew . . . . . Nothing works

How do i fix this and move ahead ?

Comment: Try `'port install sqlite3 +universal'`,
`'yum install sqlite-devel'` or `'apt-get install libsqlite3-dev'`

Comment: tried it. Does not work. How can i use port / yum / apt-get in Mac os ?

Comment: yes that is what i am suspecting as well. I tried the `brew install sqlite3` as well as `brew install sqlite`. Still no progress. Brew warns me with the following `Mac OS X already provides this software and installing another version in
parallel can cause all kinds of trouble.` and `Generally there are no consequences of this for you. If you build your
own software and it requires this formula, you'll need to add to your
build variables:

    LDFLAGS:  -L/usr/local/opt/sqlite/lib
    CPPFLAGS: -I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include`

Answer (score -1):

I had this issues too. And I finally changed the source in Gemfile to fixed it:

```
# source 'https://rubygems.org'
source 'https://ruby.taobao.org/'
```

Your error info:

> An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.10), and Bundler
>   cannot continue. Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.10'`
>   succeeds before bundling.

Bunder cannot continue, maby like this.